# Import user-specific data from a Excel-sheet into Active Directory/Exchange

Tags: excel, powershell, active-directory, ldap, administration

I would like to allocate data from a Excel-sheet (name, department, phone etc.) to available AD-users automatically.

Which programming-/scripting-language or LDAP-API is practical for this problem? Does anyone have some examples?

Answer (score 1):

Powershell or VB.  There are examples of adding / updating users from .csv data posted in the Technet Scirpt Center Repository.
http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/

Answer (score 1):

If its readily avaialble to you, go with PowerShell.

Use the [Quest AD Cmdlets](http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx) along with the Import-CSV Cmdlet. The only trick would be having to save your Excel file as a csv file. If that is not an option, you can use COM to automate excel.

Comment: Why do not use Native PowerShell V2.0 Cmdlet to access to active directory ? I understand ASDI way is not so interesting, but the Active-Directory Module is not so bad.